# jQuery plugin authoring - Multiple methods as properties of the function object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Lets say you wanted multiple methods for your jQuery plugin.  I've read that you should keep the jQuery namespace clean, and pass the method name to the plugin:

```
$('#el').plugin('method');
```

Could you add these methods to the `plugin function object`.

```
$.fn.plugin.method = function(){}
$.fn.plugin.method2 = function(){}
// etc
```

But now, these methods are called on a function object, rather than a jQuery collection.

**Could you `$.proxy()` the `plugin.method` functions so that they were called on the root jQuery collection, and work as expected?**

**Is it even OK to add properties to function 'objects'?**

Here's what the end goal might look like:

```
var $me = $('#me').person();  // init

$me.person.jump().rollOver().sleep();
```

Where jump, rollover, and sleep are methods of the `person` function object, not the jQuery.fn object.

Comment: Yes, it's okay to add properties to function objects, and it is possible to proxy them. How are you currently invoking them in your plugin code?

Comment: This is entirely hypothetical at this point

Comment: So this should interest you: [Writing Stateful Plugins with the jQuery UI Widget Factory](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/stateful-plugins-with-widget-factory/).

Comment: I took a look at jQ UI earlier to see how they do it.  Not sure if that's a direction I want to go, due to the learning curve of the widget factory system, and the dependency on the jQuery UI library.  I'm thinking something like my example above could be accomplished with jQuery alone, just not sure how that would work :-\

Comment: You only need a small piece of jQueryUI to use the widget factory, not the whole library. And it will come with all the boilerplate needed to accomplish what you want (but with a different syntax, like `$me.person('jump').person('rollover')`).